# How should I understand this clause in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, clauses

This is a sentence from a piece of [news](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/27/us/politics/devin-nunes-house-intelligence-committee-white-house-wiretap.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=first-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news) from *The New York Times*:

> Top House Democrats on Monday called on the Republican chairman of the House Intelligence Committee to recuse himself from the panel’s investigation into Russian meddling in the 2016 presidential election, thrusting the entire inquiry into jeopardy amid what they described as mounting evidence *he was too close to President Trump to be impartial*.

I don't understand the part

> thrusting the entire inquiry into jeopardy amid what they described as mounting evidence *he was too close to President Trump to be impartial*.

What kind of clause is "he was too close to President Trump to be impartial" and how is it linked to the whole sentence?

Comment: It is a a noun complement clause attached to the noun *evidence*. The complementizer *that* has been omitted. See [English Grammar: Complement Clause](https://www.englishgrammar.org/complement-clause/). See also [UEfAP](http://www.uefap.net/grammar/grammar-in-eap-nouns/grammar-in-eap-complement-clauses)

Comment: See also the chapter in *[English Grammar: A University Course](https://books.google.com/books?id=8d2cbgSAxicC&pg=PA457&lpg=PA457&dq=noun+complement+clause&source=bl&ots=BEDkFGHgpk&sig=ZmlThiiJfYJ4Y64fanLmKAE-kYA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqiYrZsvnSAhVp9IMKHR1aC2I4FBDoAQgmMAY#v=onepage&q=noun%20complement%20clause&f=false)*

Comment: "Top House Democrats on Monday called on the Republican chairman...to recuse himself from the panel's investigation....mounting evidence THAT he was too close to President Trump to be impartial  ( =the Republican chairman was so close to President Trump that he would not be impartial.) -a complement (adjectival) clause describing the noun 'evidence'.

Comment: Serious grammar does not talk of "noun clauses": it's a misnomer. The expression "(that) he was too close to President Trump to be impartial" is a declarative content clause functioning as Complement to the noun "evidence". Are you also asking about the entire clause beginning "thrusting .."?

Comment: @BillJ: thanks for your comment. The expression "(that) he was too close to President Trump to be impartial" was what confused me. Nonetheless, what kind of clause would you say about the entire clause beginning "thrusting..."?

Comment: It's clearly an adjunct, but I'm not sure what semantic category it belongs in. There's a sense in which you could talk of 'result', cf. _... with the result that the entire enquiry was thrust into jeopardy ..._.

Comment: I don't have a cited reference though, the clause "he was too close to President Trump to be impartial" seems to be an "appositive clause" according to [this article](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-9/clauses/lesson-5/noun-clauses).